# Como deixar os itens da lista um do lado do outro?

Tags: html, html5

Eu estou aprendendo HTML através de um apostila da Caelum, o problema é que por algum motivo a página ficou assim e não com os elmentos da lista um do lado do outro. Eu usei position pra isso.

Código html:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}
.menu-opcoes ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.sacola {
  background: url(img/sacola.png) no-repeat top right;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
} 

.menu-opcoes a {
  color: #003366;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 940px;
}

body {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mirrior Fashion</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="container">
   <h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mirror Fashion"></h1>
   <p class="sacola">
   Nenhum item na sacola de compras.
   </p>
   <nav class="menu-opcoes">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Sua Conta</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lista de Desejos</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cartão Fidelidade</a></li>
     <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Ajuda</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Me desculpem se o código estiver escrito de uma maneira de difícil leitura.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>Especificações Técnicas</h2>
<table id="tabelaspec">
<caption>Tabela Técnica do Google Glass <span>Mar/2013</span></caption>

  <tr><td class="ce">Tela</td><td class="cd">Resolução equivalente a tela 
  de 25"</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2" class="ce">Camera</td><td class="cd">5MP para 
  fotos</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cd">720p para vídeos</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2" class="ce">Conectividade</td><td class="cd">Wi-
  Fi</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="cd">Bluetooth</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="ce">Memória Interna</td><td class="cd">12GB</td></tr>
  </table>
```

essa seria a estruturá para você criar uma lista como uma tabela, você pode tentar trabalhar em variações dentro disso.

o código css3:

```
table#tabelaspec {
 border: 1px solid #606060;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 margin-left:auto; 
 margin-right:auto; 
}
table#tabelaspec td {
 border: 1px solid #606060;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top;
}
table#tabelaspec td.ce {
 text-align: right;
 background-color: #606060; 
 color:#ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
}
table#tabelaspec td.cd {
 background-color: #dddddd;
 text-align: left;
}
table#tabelaspec caption {
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 13pt;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
table#tabelaspec caption span {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 color: black;
 font-size: 8pt;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado com seu problema!

Answer (score 0):

Com `position absolute` você está posicionando os itens todos no mesmo lugar.

Troque para `position: relative` ou omita esse estilo na classe `.menu-opcoes ul li`. Se você deseja alinhar o menu à direita, adicione um estilo para a `ul`:

```
.menu-opcoes ul {
   float: right;
}

.menu-opcoes ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

```css
header {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-opcoes ul {
  float: right;
}

.menu-opcoes ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.sacola {
    background: url(img/sacola.png) no-repeat top right;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}   

.menu-opcoes a {
    color: #003366;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}

body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header class="container">
        <h1><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Mirror Fashion"></h1>
        <p class="sacola">
        Nenhum item na sacola de compras.
        </p>
        <nav class="menu-opcoes">
            <ul>
                <li><a  href="#">Sua    Conta</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Lista  de  Desejos</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Cartão Fidelidade</a></li>
                <li><a  href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a  href="#">Ajuda</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```